# How to enable QCA6390 Bluetooth firmware in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, bluetooth, firmware, nixos

### Context

I'm having difficulty getting the kernel to load the necessary Bluetooth firmware for my XPS 9310. My model has the AX500 connectivity chip, which uses the QCA6390.

Users of both [Ubuntu](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware/pull/207#issuecomment-727668837) and [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9310)) have reported Bluetooth working with this model, however, I'm having difficulty finding the right kernel configuration necessary to get this working on NixOS.

### My Configuration

I have enabled the following kernel configuration params with the following patch added to `boot.kernelPatches` in my nix configuration:

```
    # Extra config required for Bluetooth.
    {
      name = "enable-qca6390-bluetooth";
      patch = null;
      extraConfig = ''
        BT_QCA m
        BT_HCIBTUSB m
        BT_HCIBTUSB_AUTOSUSPEND y
        BT_HCIUART m
        BT_HCIUART_QCA y
      '';
    }
```

I'm loading the related modules like so:

```
  boot.kernelModules = [ "bluetooth" "btqca" "btusb" "hci_qca" "hci_uart" ];
```

It should go without saying that I have:

```
  hardware.bluetooth.enable = true;
```

I also have:

```
  hardware.enableRedistributableFirmware = true;
```

which, enables the [`firmwareLinuxNonfree`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/hardware/all-firmware.nix#L46) package, which in turn adds the firmware from the [linux-firmware](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a1ea95ba042964875bdb985d70934aca19ba0c6e/pkgs/os-specific/linux/firmware/firmware-linux-nonfree/default.nix#L8) repo, which in turn includes the [necessary QCA firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/qca).

### The Problem

This firmware can be observed being loaded in the `dmesg` output of two separate Ubuntu users [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware/pull/207#issuecomment-727860836) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299154/dell-xps-13-9310-bluetooth-wont-find-anything), both of which report working Bluetooth. However, I am unable to observe it being loaded in mine.

For reference, here is the `dmesg` output from a user with working Bluetooth:

```
[ 2.349008] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 2.349019] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 2.349023] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 2.349024] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 2.349028] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2.394642] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[ 2.394644] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[ 2.394645] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[ 2.394654] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[ 2.394655] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[ 2.394660] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[ 2.394702] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[ 2.394734] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[ 2.394742] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[ 2.394743] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[ 2.394748] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[ 2.416321] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[ 2.420348] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
[ 2.444937] Modules linked in: snd_pcm qrtr ns snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath11k_pci(+) mhi snd_rawmidi ath11k hci_uart qmi_helpers btqca i915(+) snd_seq btrtl uvcvideo mac80211 snd_seq_device btbcm btintel snd_timer videobuf2_vmalloc dell_wmi drm_kms_helper input_leds videobuf2_memops dell_smbios videobuf2_v4l2 cec dcdbas snd efi_pstore serio_raw rc_core videobuf2_common hid_sensor_als i2c_algo_bit hid_sensor_trigger ucsi_acpi(+) cfg80211 fb_sys_fops industrialio_triggered_buffer processor_thermal_device typec_ucsi dell_wmi_descriptor kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common intel_rapl_common soundcore industrialio wmi_bmof videodev mei_me libarc4 syscopyarea cros_ec_ishtp 8250_dw mc hid_multitouch sysfillrect mei cros_ec sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec mac_hid bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_pad intel_hid acpi_tad int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_hub
[ 2.756645] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID :0x00000010
[ 2.756647] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version :0x400a0200
[ 2.756647] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version :0x00000200
[ 2.756648] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[ 2.756650] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[ 2.756651] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[ 3.584055] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
[ 3.777754] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA setup on UART is completed
[ 3.998318] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 3.998319] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 3.998321] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 14.108234] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 14.108238] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 14.108242] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

And here is the output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` on my machine:

```
[    4.363188] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.363199] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.363201] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.363203] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.363205] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.379230] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.379231] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.379232] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    4.379238] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    4.379256] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    4.379260] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   20.090546] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.090553] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

As you can see, my Bluetooth setup never performs this step or any of the following `hci0` steps:

```
[ 2.416321] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
```

Unsurprisingly, as a result, I'm unable to enable Bluetooth in my GNOME settings GUI, and `bluetoothctl` shows nothing:

```
$ bluetoothctl list

$ bluetoothctl devices
No default controller available
```

### Questions

From my understanding, the firmware should be automatically loaded in the case that `BT_QCA` is enabled and the firmware exists, both of which should be happening as a result of my aforementioned nix configuration.

Is this assumption correct?

Am I missing a necessary step required to trigger the `hci0` lines shown above?

Any advice or ideas on how to progress would be greatly appreciated!

### System info

```
$ nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 5.10.2, NixOS, 21.03pre259798.84917aa00bf (Okapi)`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.3.10`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-21.03pre259798.84917aa00bf, home-manager-20.09"`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`
```

```
$ lsmod | grep -i bt
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                28672  2 hci_uart,btusb
btqca                  20480  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             589824  13 btrtl,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbcore               270336  5 xhci_hcd,usbhid,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #1 (rev 01)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #4 (rev 20)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #5 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b3 (rev 20)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 011a
56:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Qualcomm Device 1101
57:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:672a Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Further Reference

In case they help as a reference, here are the links to the default kernel configurations for [NixOS](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/os-specific/linux/kernel/common-config.nix), [Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/blob/master/debian/config/config) and [Arch](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/config?h=packages/linux).

Here is my WIP [PR](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware/pull/207) aimed at adding support for the XPS 9310 to NixOS that will include this work.

Here is [my previous post](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-include-and-use-external-firmware-in-nixos-config-bluetooth-for-qca6390/10471/3) to the NixOS discourse forum asking for help with this issue, yet to receive a response as of writing this.

---

#### SOLVED

We have since solved this in the nixos/nixos-hardware github repo and upstreamed the necessary kernel config patches to nixpkgs itself. Use the module in the `nixos-hardware` repo [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware/tree/master/dell/xps/13-9310) to get up and running with nixos on the xps 9310 easily.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the BIOS. In the main menu click `Connection`. There's a section called `Wireless Device Enable`. Make sure the `Bluetooth` checkbox is checked. Sometimes it's the obvious stuff `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500 with the same Bluetooth hardware (Qualcomm  QCA6390 / AX500-DBS).

I had the exact same symptom as you describe and was 'sure' that I did not disable BT via BIOS. Until I looked, to verify. To my surprise I actually did disable it.

With BT being disabled in the BIOS I found the `dmesg | grep -i blue` output to match yours (precisely!). I was missing for example these two critical log lines:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
```

`bluetoothctl devices` was showing `No default controller available`. Which is how I found your question here.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a while with the same issue after it has been working for me in the past year. Everything looked ok but it just wouldn't come up. Also the firmware downloading lines in dmesg were missing.

In the end, what fixed it, was to enter the BIOS, disable Bluetooth, boot up, reboot, enter the BIOS again, enable Bluetooth again. ¯_(ツ)_/¯